# how can I filter options based on search text in angular

Tags: angular

I was trying to filter options based on search text in angular.This is the code I am getting value when I search a I get all elements containing a but if I type abc then I shouldn't get the whole array I should get only abc.

```
filterChanged(filterText: any) {

    const ddd = filterText.target.value
    const test= this.objFlatNodeParrentTempGroup;
    
    const filtered = test.filter((chat) => {
      const searchValue = ddd.toLowerCase();
      return chat.children!.filter((user) => user.item?.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)).length > 0  ;
    });

    

    this.dataSource.data = filtered;
    this.treeControl.expandAll();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mat-tree-node is a complex object. I don't know the way your objects. So, this is the "clasic" example of FoodNodes

Before I change a bit the interfaces adding a property include

```
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  include?: boolean | undefined; //<--this 
  children?: FoodNode[];
}
```

To calculate the "include" and filter we need use recursive functions

```
  setInclude(node: FoodNode[] | undefined, text: string):boolean {
    if (node) {
      node.forEach((x) => {
        x.include = x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0;
        const include=this.setInclude(x.children, text);
        x.include=x.include || include
      });
      return node.find(x=>x.include)?true:false
    }
    return false;
  }
  onlyInclude(node:FoodNode[])
  {
    node=node.filter(x=>x.include)
    node.forEach(x=>{
      if (x.children)
        x.children=this.onlyInclude(x.children)
    })
    return node
  }
```

The filter function becames like

```
  filter(text: string) {
      if (!text) this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
      else {
        const textLower = text.toLowerCase();
        const data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TREE_DATA))
        this.setInclude(data, textLower);
        this.dataSource.data = this.onlyInclude(data)
      }
      this.treeControl.expandAll();
  }
```

To avoid the flick we can use [NgZone][1] injecting in constructor

```
  constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {...}
```

And enclosed the filter function like

```
filter(text: string) {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (!text) ...
      else {
         ...
      }
      this.treeControl.expandAll();
      this.ngZone.run(() => {});
    });
}
```

NOTE: In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expw7f?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts) I add a checkbox to show all (and mark as blod the "includes") or only show nodes that has property include)

Comment: Also how can we retain the value of the checkbox after being checked?

Answer (score 0):

How use a mat-tree-nodes

The first things to take account is that the source is a `MatTreeFlatDataSource`. That's mean that we are going to get a FlatTreeControl that works with "flatElements". That is that when we use e.g.

```
this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(...)
```

All our elements are of type TodoItemFlatNode else our dataSource.data (that is of the type, e.g. TodoItemNode)

The idea is use a class in the way

```
.display-none
{
  min-height:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

In the [first example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) of mat-tree-node use a SelectionModel to control when is selected an item or nor and to toogle the selection

```
 //in the example of Material Angular
 checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<TodoItemFlatNode>(true /* multiple */);
```

But I want that check/uncheck only take account the elements visibles (included) so our export TodoItemFlatNode add as property not only item,level and expandable else selected and include

```
class TodoItemFlatNode {
  item: string;
  include: boolean;
  selected: boolean;
  level: number;
  expandable: boolean;
}
```

So we can create an .html like

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding 
       [class.display-none]="!node.include" >
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node" 
                  [checked]="node.selected"
                  (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">
           {{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding 
        [class.display-none]="!node.include" >
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-checkbox #checkID [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)" 
                  [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node,checkID)">
     {{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

See that if !node.include the node is not showed and the checkbox are checked if node.selected

The functions like

```
transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode =
      existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.include = false;
    flatNode.selected = false;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children?.length;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  };

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected. */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every((child) => {
        return (child.selected && child.include) || !child.include;
      });
    return descAllSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some((child) => child.selected && child.include);
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the to-do item selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  todoItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode, checkID: any): void {
    node.selected = !node.selected;
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    descendants.forEach((x) => {
      if (x.include) {
        x.selected = node.selected;
      }
    });

    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
    setTimeout(() => {
      checkID.checked = node.selected;
    });
  }

  /** Toggle a leaf to-do item selection. Check all the parents to see if they changed */
  todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    node.selected = !node.selected;
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /* Checks all the parents when a leaf node is selected/unselected */
  checkAllParentsSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    let parent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = this.getParentNode(node);
    while (parent) {
      this.checkRootNodeSelection(parent);
      parent = this.getParentNode(parent);
    }
  }

  /** Check root node checked state and change it accordingly */
  checkRootNodeSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    const nodeSelected = node.selected;
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every((child) => {
        return child.selected;
      });
    if (nodeSelected && !descAllSelected) {
      node.selected = false;
    } else if (!nodeSelected && descAllSelected) {
      node.selected = true;
    }
  }

  /* Get the parent node of a node */
  getParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): TodoItemFlatNode | null {
    const currentLevel = this.getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this.getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  filter(text: string) {
    const textLower = text ? text.toLowerCase() : null;
    this.setFlatInclude(this.treeControl.dataNodes, textLower);
    this.treeControl.expandAll();
  }

  setFlatInclude(
    node: TodoItemFlatNode[] | undefined,
    text: string | null
  ): boolean {
    if (node) {
      node.forEach((x) => {
        x.include = !text || x.item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0;
        const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(x);
        const include = this.setFlatInclude(descendants, text);
        x.include = x.include || include;
      });
      return node.find((x) => x.include) ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxtfcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts)